# Android - Change `BottomNavigationView` `state_checked` color

Tags: android, android-layout

is it possible to change state checked color for each tab? 
i am able to change the `BottomNavigation` `state_checked` color by adding the selector to `BottomNavigation`.

what i need is to change the `state_checked` color on each tab. 
ie;
if i click the first icon on my `BottomNavigation` i need to change the icon `state_checked` color to green, on second icon change color to red etc..

BottomNavigationView

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/green" />
<item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

now the `state_checked` color is Green and default color is gray.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dynamically as -

```
public static StateListDrawable selectorForColor (int normalColor,int pressedColor) {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable ();
        states.addState (new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed }, 
           new ColorDrawable(pressed));
        states.addState (new int[]{ }, new ColorDrawable(normal));
        return states;
    }
```

Call this method inside your `onClick()` of `BottomNavigation` item and pass the colors you want to set for this item. You can create an `array` of colors which will have colors for the item at each `index` of `BottomNavigation`.
This method will `return` a `drawable` object which you can set to your item `view`.